# want to utilize the non-used variable values in the subsequent request - jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing perf testing using jmeter for my APIs with 100 users where I'm creating the data and deleting the data. While I create the data, I store ID in a variable and use it while deleting the data.(e.g; $.id).

now, the problem is sometimes in my delete request, I'm getting the same id multiple times and my server tries to delete already deleted record and hence my tests fail. Is there any way by which I can use the variable only once in jMeter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [JMeter Documentation on Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) it shouldn't be a problem.

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread**; properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So if you're creating the data and deleting it by the same thread (virtual user) within the bounds of the same [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) - there will be no chance for other thread to use that `id` variable as long as your correlation logic is correct.

If you're creating data in one Thread Group and deleting the data in another Thread Group - re-visit the logic where you're [converting the JMeter variables into JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) and add some prefix or postfix to it to use [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) and eventually [__iterationNum()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) to avoid different threads using the same id.